# Eclipse debug can not step into (or F5)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, step-into

```
package com.test;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TreeMap<String, String> tree = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        tree.put("1", "1");//line a
        tree.put("1", "1");//line b
        System.out.println(tree.size());
    }
}
```

I want to debug **TreeMap put** method, so i add two breakpoints for the lines (line a,line b).
Eclipse debug tool cannot step into put mentod when debugging.

I have attached source code for eclipse. when i put mouse over **put** method, press <kbd>F3</kbd> key, it can go to **TreeMap put** method source code.  I am running Eclipse SDK Version: 3.2.2

[image]

Comment: Did you check keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

download the source code from this link : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java and then attach this source into eclipse

Comment: i have attach the source into eclipse. So when press F3 key, it can go to TreeMap put method source code